# How to avoid null checking in a foreach body?

Tags: c#, .net, foreach, null

How I can avoid the condition inside foreach statements but at same time omit the processing of possible null elements?

```
public class MyObject
{
    public int Value = 0;

    public MyObject(int value) : base()
    {
        Value = value;
    }
}

class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var list = new List<MyObject>()
        {
            new MyObject(1),
            new MyObject(2),
            null,
            new MyObject(4),
            new MyObject(5)
        };

        foreach (MyObject obj in list)
        {
            if (obj != null)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(obj.Value);
            }
        }

        list.ForEach(obj =>
        {
            if (obj != null)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(obj.Value);
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: Don't put null objects inside of the list to begin with.

Comment: so your question should really be titled:  "how do I check for null without checking for null?"  **why** don't you want to check for null?

Comment: Why would you? You would make the code worse, if that was possible.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't avoid null check if you need to check for null. But you can remove null check from foreach body:

```
foreach (MyObject obj in list.Where(o => o != null))
    Console.WriteLine(obj.Value);
```

Comment: How is this not null checking...?

Comment: @tnw How to avoid null checking **in** a foreach body?

Comment: @tnw It's not *inside the body* of the loop.

Comment: the code is still doing a null check.  the question was how to reduce the checks

Comment: Kinda sorta. See documentation for [Enumerable.Where](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb534803(v=vs.110).aspx): *The query represented by this method is not executed until the object is enumerated either by calling its GetEnumerator method directly or by using foreach in Visual C# or For Each in Visual Basic.*

Comment: So basically you still null check inside the foreach.

Comment: @tnw you still think enumerator executed in foreach body? It's same as `while(enumerator.MoveNext() { Console.WriteLine(enumerator.Current.Value); }`

Comment: @SergeyBerezovskiy That's not really what I said or the documentation says. The object is enumerated by calling the foreach, THEN the query is executed (the null check). I'm forced to conclude that this essentially means the null check is still being executed inside the foreach.

Comment: @tnw The processor is actually performing the check to see if the object is null in code executing inside of the loop, yes, due to the nature of deferred execution.  The code defining the null check is outside of the body of the `foreach` loop.  If this is considered a problem, one could add a `ToList` to eagerly evaluate the null checks.

Comment: @tnw You're being pedantic. I think it's obvious that the OP simply wanted to know how to avoid their `if (obj != null)` code blocks.

Comment: @itsme86 How am I being pedantic when this solution does exactly the opposite of that?

Comment: Is everyone missing the second part of his question? OP wants to `omit the processing of possible null elements`. This is not doing that. This is quite explicitly processing null elements.

Comment: The only real solution here, if he wants to `omit the processing of possible null elements`, is to simply not have nulls in his list. Please correct me if I'm wrong.

Comment: Definitively this is the best solution, the processing instructions (console output) not process null elements. Even with less votes than another answer, this one seem to be more clear.

Comment: @rsotolongo Sorry, but this still processes null elements. Please read the discussion above.

Comment: @tnw first, text in my answer describes clearly what happens. Second, I believe making null-check explicit is much more readable in this case, than replacing it with `is` operator. And last, I will not say what is better - null-check in foreach body or filtering out null from source collection. Both solutions seems readable to me - one is explicit and provides best performance, latter is also very readable and allows to do filtering even before looping items.

Comment: @rsotolongo thanks! As I stated in previous comment, your solution also looks very good to me - it has best performance and it's very easy to understand. And last note - do not ever use exceptions for flow control!

Comment: @SergeyBerezovskiy Indeed! I wasn't responding to your answer... I was responding to OP's comment which seemed to be under the misapprehension that that was not the case. It's a little confusing.

Answer (score 8):

You can use the `OfType` method

```
foreach (MyObject obj in list.OfType<MyObject>())
```

Answer (score 2):

By controlling what is placed inside your lists.  If you don't allow nulls to be added you have nothing to worry about.

Answer (score 1):

```
list.Where(x=>x!=null).ForEach(x=>Console.WriteLine(x.Value));
```

Comment: Thank you but you forgot to call ToList() method after Where clause (IEnumerable don't have ForEach extension method).

Answer (score 1):

Here: no "check" for null, and yet you don't process null objects.

```
foreach (var obj in list)
{
    try
    {
        // obj.GetType(); -- if you want to FORCE an NRE, you could do this to avoid any side effects of the next line
        doThingWithObj(obj);
    }
    catch (NullReferenceException)
    {
        // look ma, no null check!
    }
}
```

**Edit**: I never stated that this was a *good* solution to the question.  I only state that it does *exactly* what the OP wanted.  Frankly, it is a **horrible idea** to me, but the OP hasn't ever explained **why** they want what they want.  in really old java performance stuff, the way java set up exceptions meant omitting null checks and catching null pointer exceptions could be *hugely* more efficient if nulls were *very* rare (iirc, < 1:1000).  But other than that, I think this is a very bad idea.

Comment: wow, a downvote!  nice!  it does exactly what the op wants, no null check! :D

Comment: +1 for a perfectly good response... though I wouldn't say its the *best*, it still answers the question.

Comment: I try! :P Especially when the OP doesn't respond to comments about what they really want to do or why they want what they want.

Comment: @tnw It makes me sad inside that you would advocate intentionally throwing a NRE and catching it as a preferable option to checking an object for null.  Regardless of whether or not it is an answer to the question, it is clearly not *helpful* as an answer by any means.  That three different people sincerely feel that this is a good idea is baffling to me.

Comment: +1 as I was in the process of writing the same answer; either the OP has to filter out non-nulls or they have to take responsibility for handling them, there's no other way...

Comment: You're kidding? That's thousand times worse than an if-statement.

Comment: @Servy - really? the OP has specifically asked to *avoid* the `null` check!

Comment: @Servy Eh? I said it wasn't the best solution, but it's a solution nonetheless. It's perfectly obvious there's better solutions. Calm down.

Comment: @StephenByrne Yes.  And?  Does that make this a good solution to the problem that the OP has?  Should this actually be used?  If no, it's a bad answer, if you think yes, again, it makes me sad.

Comment: @tnw But you upvoted it.  That means that you think that the solution is useful/helpful, and that you're advocating others use it.  It doesn't mean "this technically answers the literal question, even if it's a bad idea."

Comment: @Servy - the OP's question doesn't give any context - perhaps having null in their collection is an error condition. So why should a potentially exceptional event not be caught?

Comment: @StephenByrne If it's an error condition then you shouldn't be catching the error; you should just be omiting the null check and letting any errors propagate.  *That* would likely not only be a solution, but possibly even the best.  This doesn't do that.  This intentionally throws the NRE only to catch it again.

Comment: @Servy yes, it does.  you could intentionally omit the line that causes a NRE, but I don't know what the processing is, and if it does anything that has any side-effects from processing. maybe the do work stuff adds the null to another collection and causes more issues.  I added an edit that I think this is a **horrible** idea, but until the OP explains what they **really** want to do, this is a way to avoid "checking for null" and yet not process null objects.

Comment: @JohnGardner Precisely why its the only answer I upvoted besides T McKeown's.

Comment: @tnw that's the one I upvoted too.

Comment: @JohnGardner So you're intentionally advocating the use of a solution that you feel is a *horrible* idea.  What about that sounds like a good idea?  If you don't see a good solution to the problem given the information given then *don't try to answer the question*, but rather ask clarifying questions until you feel the question is answerable.

Comment: @Servy I don't think he's actually advocating the use of this solution. In fact, I think he's saying exactly the opposite by saying it's not a good idea. Not sure why you keep saying he's advocating its use. IMO it's perfectly acceptable to discuss solutions that *work* but shouldn't really be used as long as it's perfectly clear what the context for the answer is.

Comment: @Servy - I really don't think this is worth arguing about since we can argue the semantics of where exceptions should or should not be handled on a more relevant question sometime.  If nothing else this answer can serve as a "here's one way you might think of doing it and why you probably shouldn't." :)

Comment: @Servy i'm not avocating using it at all.  I'm simply stating it is in the *universe of possible answers to the OP's overly broad question*, hence my original comment on the question saying "so the question should be titled how do I check for null without checking for null?"  And "ask clarifying questions until answerable" is what I did.  I have a comment on the original question, and the OP hasn't clarified *anything anywhere*.

Comment: @tnw When you're posting something as an answer it is implicitly advocating it's use.  If it shouldn't be used, then why post it to begin with, especially if you're not also including what you consider an acceptable solution in the same post.

Comment: @JohnGardner If you feel a question can't be answered as it is, and thus ask clarifying questions to understand it, and nobody responds, then the solution is not to answer the question anyway, but rather to not answer it and consider closing it.

Comment: @Servy *shrug*. It is a *valid* answer to the question, is it not?  It meets the OP's needs.  This is stackoverflow, not perfectanswerville.

Comment: @JohnGardner The answer is *unhelpful*, regardless of whether or not it answers the literal question asked.  SO strives to be a place where people come to get *quality* answers, not answers that answer the question and provide (in your own words and emphasis) a **horrible** solution.

Comment: @Servy I'm of the opinion that showing both good and bad solutions *is* actually helpful. If we only show good solutions, how are learners supposed to know what a bad solution is until they unwittingly do something like this?

Comment: @tnw Yet you don't describe how it *should* be done.  Additionally; the fact that so many people have upvoted the answer is an indication to the reader that the solution *isn't* a bad solution.

Comment: @Servy Eh? This isn't my answer. Not to mention that the context is pretty obvious, this solution exists besides the good answers *and* was added after them. You seem to be ignoring that in addition to ignoring, over and over again, that the OP of this answer explicitly states that it's bad solution.

Comment: @Servy I don't know if it is unhelpful, only the OP knows.  Like I stated in my edit, at least in java, skipping null checks and handling a very rare null pointer was a very valid java performance idiom at one point.

Comment: @tnw You upvoted it before the edit, and I've stated that I don't see it as helpful as it's doing nothing but tempting the reader to use it.

Comment: I removed my negative vote just because you clarified that your solution is a REALLY BAD idea, even when, "literally", it solves my problem, but I can't agree more with @Servy because StackOverflow as most of other Internet services allow users to write anything but that is not the case. The idea is you try to help as much as possible to developers that have issues in their apps, proposing bad solutions (consciously) is bad for everybody.

Comment: @JohnGardner "I don't know if it is unhelpful, only the OP knows"  That's what's so nice about SO.  The OP is not the only judge of helpfulness.  Any reader is free to judge the helpfulness of a post and vote accordingly.  If that quote were true, voting wouldn't exist.  Next, skipping a null check and letting a NRE be thrown when you shouldn't have null data is *fine*.  As I said before, that's likely a *great* solution.  What's not great is then catching that exception to use it for expected control flow.  If it's exceptional, it should be left to bubble up.

Comment: Then @rsotolongo, you need to clarify your question.  why do you want to not check for null, and yet avoid nulls?

Comment: @Servy Ugh. Both of you are still completely ignoring the fact that he added context that it shouldn't be used. I'm confused how you're doing a logical backflip to conclude that it is therefore encouraging someone to use it. If you aren't interested in a rational discussion, I'm bowing out. Thanks.

Comment: @Servy that isn't true though, as the OP is the only person who can mark an answer "correct".  It is entirely possible for a negative voted answer to be marked correct by the OP. so users can vote that it is good or bad form, but only the OP can say if it is helpful or not by marking it correct.

Comment: @JohnGardner The OP's vote has more weight when it comes to evaluating an answer, but to say that it is the only opinion that matters is clearly false.  The *purpose* of voting on the site is for the entire community to provide their opinion of the helpfulness of any given post, and this clearly isn't ignored by the system either.

Comment: @Servy Thank you for keep the conversation on fire, but leave John Gardner perusing his own goals (maybe generate traffic or increase reputation based on vague answers). Save your time for other needy developers.

Comment: @rsotolongo - that's hardly a fair thing to say - the guy took time  to try to answer your question. Which, I might add, is hardly a bastion of clarity, if vagueness is the issue here...as it is, his answer has led to a discussion on both the (de)merits of deliberately throwing exceptions *and* a debate on the SO community system, hardly a bad thing.

Answer (score 0):

Another not-very good idea that might be possible:

Use `struct` instead of `class`?  Then you're *guaranteed* to be non-null, and never need null checks.

Comment: i'm on downvote-fire today! :D  I'm tempted to keep posting really bad answers until the OP clarifies the question....

Comment: I can't use struct because solution uses classes, that's it. There is no much context to clarify. The question and code is pretty simple.

Comment: @rsotolongo no, there's lots of things to clarify.  why do you not want to check for null?  Is it a rare case?  Is it only for matter of style?  is catching the occasional exception fine?